# RecordingProxy::releaseRecordingFrame repeating in log every 25ms while recording on Android phone

Tags: android, video, android-camera

When I video record in my home made app I get these two lines repeating every 25ms or so (it then fills a log file in no time):

```
04-28 09:33:07.705: V/Camera(3161): RecordingProxy::releaseRecordingFrame
04-28 09:33:07.705: V/Camera(3161): releaseRecordingFrame
```

I don't think this is normal since I also get often an infamous "media server died" error or the movie just crash. This is on an 4.0.4 Samsung Discover device. I don't see these log lines on my LG optimus one devices.

You'd find these lines of logs in the code [here](http://www.androidcodesearch.com/source/frameworks/av/camera/Camera.cpp) each time a "// callback from camera service when timestamped frame is ready". Is it normal? I read that putting too much into log would eventualy slow down/ bug an app. More code following. Thanks!

Here is the log in video start:

```
04-28 09:33:05.635: V/Camera-JNI(3161): unlock
04-28 09:33:05.635: V/Camera-JNI(3161): get_native_camera: context=0x1287378, camera=0x1473a88
04-28 09:33:05.635: V/Camera-JNI(3161): get_native_camera: context=0x1287378, camera=0x1473a88
04-28 09:33:05.635: V/Camera(3161): getProxy
04-28 09:33:05.645: V/MediaProfilesJNI(3161): native_get_camcorder_profile: 0 1
04-28 09:33:05.665: D/ASC(3161): mounted
04-28 09:33:05.685: V/VoirCam(3161): ts 1398691985695
04-28 09:33:05.925: V/Camera(3161): RecordingProxy::startRecording
04-28 09:33:05.925: V/Camera(3161): reconnect
04-28 09:33:05.925: V/Camera(3161): startRecording
04-28 09:33:06.305: V/Camera(3161): RecordingProxy::releaseRecordingFrame
04-28 09:33:06.305: V/Camera(3161): releaseRecordingFrame
04-28 09:33:06.325: V/Camera(3161): RecordingProxy::releaseRecordingFrame
04-28 09:33:06.325: V/Camera(3161): releaseRecordingFrame
04-28 09:33:06.325: V/Camera(3161): RecordingProxy::releaseRecordingFrame
04-28 09:33:06.325: V/Camera(3161): releaseRecordingFrame
04-28 09:33:06.345: V/Camera(3161): RecordingProxy::releaseRecordingFrame
04-28 09:33:06.345: V/Camera(3161): releaseRecordingFrame
04-28 09:33:06.375: V/Camera(3161): RecordingProxy::releaseRecordingFrame
04-28 09:33:06.375: V/Camera(3161): releaseRecordingFrame
```

and on stop:

```
04-28 09:29:38.555: V/Camera(3161): RecordingProxy::releaseRecordingFrame
04-28 09:29:38.555: V/Camera(3161): releaseRecordingFrame
04-28 09:29:38.695: V/Camera(3161): RecordingProxy::releaseRecordingFrame
04-28 09:29:38.695: V/Camera(3161): releaseRecordingFrame
04-28 09:29:38.705: V/Camera(3161): RecordingProxy::stopRecording
04-28 09:29:38.705: V/Camera(3161): stopRecording
04-28 09:29:39.065: V/Camera-JNI(3161): lock
04-28 09:29:39.065: V/Camera-JNI(3161): get_native_camera: context=0x1287378, camera=0x1473a88
04-28 09:29:39.065: V/Camera-JNI(3161): lock
04-28 09:29:39.065: V/Camera-JNI(3161): get_native_camera: context=0x1287378, camera=0x1473a88
```

Recording starts like this:

```
    if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
        mMediaRecorder.start();
   }
```

My prepareVideoRecorder function is:

private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){

```
mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
// Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
mCamera.unlock();
mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
// Step 2: Set sources
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);

    camcorderProfile.videoCodec = MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264;
  camcorderProfile.audioCodec = MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC;
    camcorderProfile.fileFormat = MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4;


// Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)

mMediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);
// Step 4: Set output file

mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());

mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());


// Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
try {
    mMediaRecorder.prepare();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
    releaseMediaRecorder();
    return false;
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
    releaseMediaRecorder();
    return false;
}
return true;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message is not expected to appear, but perhaps not for the reason you'd expect.

In the Android sources, verbose-level logging (ALOGV) is compiled out by default.  To enable it, you define the symbol `LOG_NDEBUG` to be zero before including the `Log.h` header.  Looking at the source file that came up in your androidcodesearch.com link, you can see this #define -- commented out -- on line 18.  If you were debugging the Camera implementation, you'd start by uncommenting that line.

It appears that whoever built the system you're using (Samsung?) enabled verbose logging for this file and left it on, so messages that were only intended to be visible during debugging are always on.

I haven't looked at this code before, but I'd guess that function might normally run once per frame.  So what you're seeing is probably "normal".

Comment: Geez... So someone at Samsung was sleeping during the release ?!? Not aware of ways to force not-log, are you?

Comment: No.  You can filter the messages out so you don't see them streaming past, but they'll still fill the ring buffer.  Your best bet is to send the logcat output to a file, e.g. `ANDROID_LOG_TAGS=Camera:d adb logcat -v threadtime > log.txt` will ignore all verbose-level messages with the Camera tag.  Sending it to a file should help avoid losing stuff when the on-device buffer fills.  DDMS has similar filtering abilities.